# Create a date from a string like this "20161126 00:00" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the quickest way to create a new Date in javascript from a string in this format "20161126 00:00"

I'm using some split like these:

```
parseDateTime = (dateTime) ->
        dateArray = dateTime.split(" ");
        date = dateArray[0]
        time = dateArray[1]
        year = 
        month = 
        day =
        hour = time.split(':')[0]
        minute = time.split(':')[1]
```

but I hope you can find a quickest and simple way.

Comment: is `20161126` alsways the `yyyy:mm:dd` format in this context?

Comment: yes, the format is always the same

Comment: momentjs would be easy way if you can use it

Answer (score 1):

use a regex to get the parts, then create a new Date:

`var parts = dateTimeStr.match(/^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)$/);
var d = new Date(+parts[1], +parts[2] - 1, +parts[3], +parts[4], +parts[5]);`

only that easy if your format is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) if the `yyyy:mm:dd` date format is always the same.
note that This method extracts the characters in a string between "start" and "end", not including "end" itself.

```js
var dateTime = "20161126 00:00";
dateArray = dateTime.split(" ");
        date = dateArray[0];
        time = dateArray[1];
        year = date.substring(0, 4);
        month = date.substring(4, 6);
        day = date.substring(6, 8);
        hour = time.split(':')[0];
        minute = time.split(':')[1];
        console.log("the dateTime variable: "+dateTime+", date: "+date+", time: "+time+", year: "+year+", month: "+month+", day: "+day+", hour: "+hour+", minute: "+minute );
```